# How do I change the button text in an internationalized message box in Swing

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

I'm trying to get the Java Swing messagebox to pick up translations using the resource bundle.  I can get it to do everything else except the OK button, Cancel button and Yes/No buttons.  Does anyone know if the Swing messagebox picks up translations?

Apologies - this is the shortest piece of code I could make up to illustrate the problem

```
package s17xlat;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ShowMbox extends JFrame {
    // Keep compiler happy
    static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
    ResourceBundle m_rb = null;
    JPanel m_panel;
    Map<AbstractButton, String> m_buttons;

    public void create()
    {   
        rbRedo(Locale.getDefault());
        JButton btnEnglish = new JButton();
        rbTag(btnEnglish, "english");
        btnEnglish.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    rbRedo(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }
            });
        JButton btnKlingon = new JButton();
        rbTag(btnKlingon, "klingon");
        btnKlingon.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    // Create a new Klingon locale
                    rbRedo(new Locale("kl", "KL"));
                }
            });
        JButton btnInformation = new JButton();
        rbTag(btnInformation, "information");
        btnInformation.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        m_panel,
                        rbTag("tldr"),
                        rbTag("information"),
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            });

        m_panel = new JPanel();
        m_panel.add(btnEnglish);
        m_panel.add(btnKlingon);
        m_panel.add(btnInformation);

        add(m_panel);
        setTitle("ShowMbox Test");
        setSize(300,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    void rbRedo(Locale in_locale)
    {
        if (m_buttons == null)
            m_buttons = new HashMap<AbstractButton, String>();

        try
        {
            if (m_rb != null)
                ResourceBundle.clearCache();
            final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            File anyfile = new File(dir);
            URL[] urls = { anyfile.toURI().toURL() };
            ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            m_rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("rosetta", in_locale, loader);

            if (!m_buttons.isEmpty())
            {
                // Refresh the buttons - should do the title as well
                for (AbstractButton button: m_buttons.keySet())
                {
                    String key = m_buttons.get(button);
                    button.setText(m_rb.getString(key));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(ABORT);
        }
        catch (MissingResourceException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString() + "(" + e.getClassName() +".properties)");
            System.exit(ABORT);
        }
    }

    String rbTag(String in_key)
    {
        return m_rb.getString(in_key);
    }

    void rbTag(AbstractButton var_button, String in_key)
    {
        m_buttons.put(var_button,  in_key);

        String xlat = m_rb.getString(in_key);
        var_button.setText(xlat);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    ShowMbox self = new ShowMbox();
                    self.create();
                    self.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I'm in the UK so rosetta_en_GB.properties is

```
english=English
klingon=Klingon
information=Information
tldr=Too Long Don't Read
OK=Oh Kay
```

The Klingon version is rosetta_kl_KL.properties

```
english=English Hol
klingon=Tlhlngan
information=De'
tldr=je qaStaHvIS Qo' laD
OK=Lu'
```

What I'd like to know is

1. If I want it to pick up "Oh Kay" in English and "Lu'" in Klingon, what should the tag be called?
2. How or where do I find out what these tags are called in the message box.

If the tags cannot be changed, then I'll probably have to write my own messagebox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` you can use the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` method where you can customize more options.

For your code:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    m_panel,
    rbTag("tldr"),
    rbTag("information"),
    JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    new Object[]{ rbTag("OK") },
    null);
```

Comment: So if I use the YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, presumably, I just use *new Object[]{ rbTag("yes"), rbTag("no"), rbTag("cancel")}*.  That is a lot easier than trying to find out what the key is in UIManager.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=86180 .   Basically I wasn't searching for the correct keywords: should have been JOptionPane instead of MessageBox.

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", m_rb.getString("ok"));
```

The other OptionPane buttons are

- OptionPane.noButtonText
- OptionPane.yesButtonText
- OptionPane.cancelButtonText